# Как разместить слова разных размеров по одной оси?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Если два слова - одно большего размера, а другое меньшего. Как сделать так, чтобы эти слова выровнялись по одной оси на css?

Спасибо.

P.S. Ось - это серединная линия, если что.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
div span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/75vkg6zL/)

UPD. line-height задавать не надо

Comment: @soledar10 это как раз мой случай

Comment: В этом случае, для div разве не нужно давать display: table-cell; ?

Comment: Нет. Но это свойство и для table-cell работает и для inline-block.. ну и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте один интерлиньяж `line-height` для каждого слова.